# React paint is only executed after UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I am trying to execute two (slow) functions with a render and paint of my component in between (ie. the content should appear at that point in time on the screen) and am using UseEffect for this purpose to avoid slowing down the UI. However, although the render is indeed executed in between my function calls, the paint only appears after the second function has executed.

```js
export default function MainComponent({propA}) {
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState(undefined);

    // compute function only if selection changes (should be after paint of probabilities)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof selection === 'undefined') {
            return
        }
        secondFunction()
    }, [selection])


    const firstFunction = async () => {
        const s = await verySlowStuff()
        setSelection(s)
        return true
    }


    return (
        <div>
           {/* Paint selection in between functions */}
           {(typeof selection === 'undefined') ?
              null
              : selection
           }
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={firstFunction}>
                First.
            </Button>
       </div>
    );
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Why is the paint only executing after `secondFunction` is done?

Comment: hmm what paint?

Comment: by paint I mean, the ``selection`` appears on the screen (I edited the main question for more clarity)

Comment: where do you call `firstFunction `? And can you put that in a sandbox?

Comment: where is firstFunction

Comment: firstFunction is called from a button click, will edit the question accordingly

Comment: Assuming secondFunction is async function. Try to call it with the syntax "await ..."